# Windows 10 - Sound settings for unilateral hearing loss

Tags: windows-10, audio

I have been deaf in my left ear since birth and I was wondering if there is a way to set up headphones so that the sound is combined into one channel.

Microsoft used to have good support for this but I can't find ANYTHING on google for this now.

I know that the iPhone has a setting in ease of access which combines audio in both headphones for people with UHL then they just select which ear is the good ear.

Does Microsoft products have this feature? (Windows 10) If so, how do I set it up?

Answer (score 0):

More of a hardware hack, but if you short out the left and right connectors together (put a small bit of solder bridging the gap between the tip and the first ring) you will turn the stereo headphones into combined mono.

[image]

Comment: Soldering is a bit drastic, and done improper could mess things up. todays jacks will melt easily.  You can have some recordings out there with phase canceling causing mono problems. http://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-107160-Stereo-Adaptor-Plated/dp/B001RCZ14U/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1462521622&sr=8-3&keywords=stereo+mono+adapter   These adapters you should be able to get at any electronic store. Which still leaves the problem of adapter hanging out to get damaged. They also make stereo mono adapter "wires" short wires that would do it.   Same idea as what your saying just different method.